# Switch row value into column header file and cell value

Tags: python, pandas

My excel content had header file position in 0th & 2nd row and 1st & 4th row is value which is not constant value; i need a 2nd row header file and there below reference value to move to column "R & S" in row 0th position.

```
0| JobFolder | JobName     |Revision |ModifiedDate |column E to Q|Unnamed: 17|
1|   \BANK   | CH2589_62   |DD       |10/18/2023   |             |           |
2|TotalSlots | Placedparts |
3|   348     | 59          |
```

(jobfolder) in a "A" Column and (unnamed) in "R" Column.

Note* Row 0 & Row 2 are a Header File which is a default name.
Note* Row 1 & Row 3 are a cell value which will change by the data we get are not a constant value.

what i required:

```
0| JobFolder | JobName   |Revision |Column D-to-Q| TotalSlots |Placedparts|
1|   \BANK   | CH2589_62 |   DD    |             |    348     |    59     |
```

Row 2 to Row 3 which i need to move to Col "R" & "S".

i make the table look shorter. row Range "4" Col range "S"

Comment: Please click on `caps lock` and rewrite your question.

Comment: Writing in all upper-case is considered shouting. And it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you. Please [edit] your question to stop shouting at us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['TotalSlots'] = ''
df['TotalSlots'].iloc[0] = df['JobFolder'].iloc[2]

df['Placedparts'] = ''
df['Placedparts'].iloc[0] = df['JobName'].iloc[2]

print(df.drop(index=[1,2]))



  JobFolder JobName   Revision  ModifiedDate    Unnamed: 17 TotalSlots  Placedparts
0   \BANK   CH2589_62   DD        10/18/2023        NaN      348          59
```

Comment: sir thanks i tried with my data but i facing error in i like to post what faced.

Comment: What`s error you have?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({"JobFolder": ['', 'TotalSlots',''],
                  "JobName": ['', 'PlacedParts','']})

df['TotalSlots'] = ''
df['TotalSlots'].iloc[0] = df['JobFolder'].iloc[2]

df['PlacedParts'] = ''
df['PlacedParts'].iloc[0] = df['JobName'].iloc[2]

print(df.drop(index=[1, 2])) if i run with other value \police it facing error. other data had \blank and other data had \teacher. i update my question please check it up.

Comment: df['TotalSlots'].iloc[1] = df['JobFolder'].iloc[2]
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: You need df['TotalSlots'].iloc[0] = df['JobFolder'].iloc[2]. You use pd.read_excel() for open your file in python?

Comment: df['TotalSlots'] = ''
df['TotalSlots'].loc[0] = df['JobFolder'].loc[2]

df['PlacedParts'] = ''
df['PlacedParts'].loc[0] = df['JobName'].loc[2]

print(df.drop(index=[1, 2])) worked thanks you

Comment: Please upvote my answer and mark it like a solution.